# How can I make my word lookup cleaner and more efficient?

Tags: c++

Write a program that “bleeps” out words that you don’t like; that is, you read in words using cin and print them
again on cout. If a word is among a few you have defined, you write out BLEEP instead of that word. Start with
one “disliked word” such as
string disliked = “Broccoli”;
When that works, add a few more.

So i was thinking on how i could create a code that would do that with a set of words using a vector, but all i could come up with was

```
int main()
{
    vector<string> disliked = { "damn","stupid","fat" };
    string word = "";

    while (cin >> word) {
        bool bad = false;
        for (string x : disliked) {
            if (x == word)
                bad = true;
        }
        if (bad)
            cout << "Bleep\n";
        else
            cout << word << "\n";
    }


    return 0;
}
```

i feel like that code can be shortened with taking out one of the if statements but i can't find a working way to do it.
overall it seems like more code than it should be for this simple check, also could  the for part be done better? doing a whole loop of the whole vector seems to be too resource intensive in a case where the vector has lets say a 1000 words, maybe separating it by an if statement checking for a-d, f-j... etc, and then only running a for loop would be less heavy?

Comment: You should look up the keyword break

Comment: Before shortening up the code, have you explored it's efficiency?

Comment: In the future, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a good place to post questions like this - when you have working code but want to explore improvements to it.

Comment: But note that like here, code for review should include the necessary headers and `using` directives (though `using namespace std;` is discouraged, as it's a dangerous practice).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on code review

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort your vector and use [`std::binary_search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/binary_search):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> disliked = { "damn","stupid","fat" };
    sort(std::begin(disliked), std::end(disliked));
    std::string word = "";

    while (std::cin >> word)
    {
        if ( binary_search(std::begin(disliked), std::end(disliked), word))
        {
            std::cout << "Bleep ";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << word;
        }
    }
}
```

or use [`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) instead of vector:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::set<std::string> disliked = { "damn","stupid","fat" };
    std::string word = "";

    while (std::cin >> word)
    {
        if ( disliked.find(word) != std::end(disliked) )
        {
            std::cout << "Bleep ";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << word;
        }
    }
}
```

Both of these solutions have logarithmic complexity for the word lookup instead of linear.

Comment: Thank you! helped alot, understood the vector part .but the .find != .end is hard to understand (did google , still cant understand).

Comment: [`std::set::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/find) returns an iterator pointing to the found item. If it was not found, it returns the end iterator. Does that help?

Comment: Yeah it actually cleared it all up :).
Thank your for your huge help !

Answer (score 1):

Use the `std::find` operation on a vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<string> disliked = { "damn","stupid","fat" };
    string word = "";

    while (cin >> word) {
        if ( std::find(disliked.begin(), disliked.end(), word) != disliked.end() )
        {
            cout << "Bleep ";
        }
        else
        {
            cout << word;
        }
    }
   return 0;
}
```